# How to install JavaScript in Internet Explorer 9 or 10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, plugins, add-on, browser-addons

I have 1 JavaScript file. I would like to install it in Internet Explorer 9 or 10, just the way as we install JavaScript in Firefox by using GreaseMonkey. Is there any plug-in like GreaseMonkey in Internet Explorer ?
Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trixie](http://www.pcworld.com/product/952510/trixie.html)--just download and install it, and it will show up in the IE Tools menu.

You can either grab scripts made for Trixie or go to the main Greasemonkey script repository, Userscripts.org, and try those out--many of the authors test for Trixie compatibility as well.